# Android Google Maps Tutorial

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I´ve tried to do this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ 
but the application crashes without error.
I have some errors in the log cat file, but no idea what they mean, help please. :(

PS: I Can`t imagine anyone finding errors with cat log, is there any other way?

Edit: Buggy page won´t let me post the code...so i´ll use a dropbox text file. Sorry for the inconvinience.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftwdqtvd51inszb/log.txt

Comment: why wouldnt we be able to find the error with the start trace?

Comment: the meta tag should be inside applicatiion tag, the error says you cannot connect to network

Comment: because it spams about 10.000 errors per second and after that it spams the second one... I can´t think of anyone finding a problem is this mess :/

Comment: thanks Raghuandan reduced my errors by like 99%. But it´s still crashing on execution. I updated the Cat log in the drop box.

Answer (score 2):

In your activity, this:

```
 class MainActivity extends Activity
```

should be:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

To solve the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
```

By not having a modifier in front of your class, sub-classes and global classes do not have access to it. More general information about modifiers:
[Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)